# Chrome not loading map markers due to tab

Tags: google-maps, google-chrome, google-maps-api-3

I have a google map page, which works fine in every browser but Chrome. When Chrome loads it, it thinks the add tab is trying to add a browser tab instead of a tab in the infobox. Any ideas? Thanks in advance. Here is the code snippet in question.

```
// to open the info bubbles
             google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                 InfoBubble.open(map, marker);
                 InfoBubble.removeTab(4);
                 InfoBubble.removeTab(3);
                 InfoBubble.removeTab(2);
                 InfoBubble.removeTab(1);
                 InfoBubble.removeTab(0);
                 if (category == "KML") {
                     window.open("" + url);
                 }
                 //if (!category == "KML") {
                 InfoBubble.addTab('Details', contentString_detail);
                 //}
                 if (!notes_tab == "") {
                     InfoBubble.addTab('Notes', contentString_notes);
                 }
                 if (!map_tab == "") {
                     switch (category) {
                         case "Camping": InfoBubble.addTab('Campsite Map', contentString_maps);
                             break;
                         case "Hike": InfoBubble.addTab('Trail Map', contentString_maps);
                             break;
                     }
                 }
                 if (!hiking_detail_tab == "") {
                     InfoBubble.addTab('Trail Notes', contentString_hiking_detail);
                 }
                 if (!camping_detail_tab == "") {
                     InfoBubble.addTab('Campsite Notes', contentString_camping_detail);
                 }
             });
         }
```

Comment: You have a jsfiddle that shows the problem?

Comment: I used http://jsfiddle.net, which I'm not all that familar with, and it runs with no issues, however, it doesn't load the markers so you really can't tell. http://jsfiddle.net/2pourdrummer/yHvRy/

Comment: Can you modify it to load a few sample markers so we can see the problem?

Comment: I don't think that the addTab-method forces chrome to open a new browser-tab, I'm sure the opened tab is a result of `window.open("" + url);`

Comment: I will try to get a marker uploaded sometime today. Having an issue right now with it. If it is the window.open, then how do I fix it?

Comment: I don't have the fiddle working, but you can see a working copy at http://www.troop993bac.org/maps.aspx